# SQL - Getting distinct ID that the data is not in the record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named Supplier.

```
ID  SupplierGroup
101 FAC_A
101 FAC_B
101 FAC_C
101 FAC_D
202 FAC_A
202 FAC_B
202 FAC_D
303 FAC_B
303 FAC_C
303 FAC_D
404 FAC_A
404 FAC_B
404 FAC_C
404 FAC_D
505 FAC_C
505 FAC_D
```

I have to get the distinct ID of the Suppliers not having FAC_A as the SupplierGroup. I used this query..

```
select distinct ID
  from Supplier
  where SupplierGroup not in ('FAC_A')
```

but there's something wrong with my query. it resulted to

```
ID
101
202
303
404
505
```

It should get the result of

```
ID 
303
505
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use NOT EXISTS:

```
select distinct s.ID
from Supplier s
where
  not exists (select * from Supplier
              where supplier.ID=s.ID and
              supplier.SupplierGroup ='FAC_A')
```

another solution is to use GROUP BY and count the FAC_A values:

```
select ID
from Supplier
group by ID
having
  sum(case when SupplierGroup ='FAC_A' then 1 else 0 end)=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way with OUTER APPLY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.ID
FROM Supplier s
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Supplier WHERE SupplierGroup IN ('FAC_A') AND ID = s.ID) p
WHERE p.ID IS NULL
```

Output:

```
ID
303
505
```

Comment: Thanks @gofr1 it works also. OUTER APPLY is new to me. Thank you also for additional learning. :)